# Is the risk a probability?

Tags: probability, risk, ripley-k

The [`Ktest`](https://ericmarcon.github.io/dbmss/reference/Ktest.html) function in the [`dbmss` package](https://ericmarcon.github.io/dbmss/index.html) returns:

> the risk to reject CSR erroneously, based on the distribution of the K function

Below that (as far as I understand) it states that this risk is a p-value.
How is "risk" to be interpreted? Can I always equate risk with probability? Is the risk always a p-value?

Comment: The risk is explained in the quotation: it is the chance that the CSR hypothesis will be rejected.  It is not a p-value, because the p-value is specific to the dataset whereas the risk (as defined in the quotation) is a property of the underlying process.  Presumably, this function can only *estimate* that risk (most likely *via* simulation).  For an authoritative answer, consult the documentation.

Comment: "*it is the chance that the CSR hypothesis will be rejected*", is the *chance* not a probability?

Comment: Yes, a chance is a probability.